# Calculated Column- First Name from Full Name

Tags: 2016, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to write a calculated column formula to return the First Name from a Full Name column. The issue is, that the full names are displayed in different formats:

```
Jacob J. Smith
Peter Grabowski
Anna Maria Gonzales
```

Comment: What are the expected results for above name examples? "Jacob J.", "Peter", "Anna Maria" or "Jacob", "Peter", "Anna"?

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are looking for :

[image]

Then here is the formula that you need to use inside your Calucalted column :

```
=LEFT(Title,FIND(" ",Title)-1)
```

Replace Title with your FullName column Static name

Comment: You're a STAR :* Thank you.

Comment: Great to hear that it helped, thank you for marking my answer as a solution. Let me know if you need anything else